# Wheel Spokes: fewer thick vs many thin

Tags: wheels

Are there any advantages between fewer [Thick Spokes](http://www.rotawheels.com/wheel.php?id=65) and many [Thin Spokes](http://www.rotawheels.com/wheel.php?id=19)?

Structurally  -  Weight  -  Brake Heat/Cooling  -  Maintenance/Cleaning?

Application will be 17x8 +48 for a performance daily driver, summer use only.

Comment: They all ensure the same minimum specs due to the law. Check the weight and evaluate the data. Less weight is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling is pretty much the only real difference here. There is no inherent advantage to one over the other. Obviously The manufacturer is going to test their wheels to ensure the wheel meets a particular spec they (or the DOT) setup. Many wheels with thinner appearing spokes will actually run deeper into the wheel. While you don't see the extra material, it's there for added strength. The only way to make a large difference in strength is to have a solid center on the rim. If you think about rims, though, it's not usually the spokes which will exhibit problems: the outer rim will give first. With all of the abuse wheels take, it's in the outer rim where the damage will occur fist, not the spokes. It takes a lot of stress to damage a wheel ... not that they cannot be damaged, just they put up with a lot of abuse.